# Abstract class for thread-related class without multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance, abc

I want to create an abstract class for thread-related class. Class that want to enable threading must inherit `threading.Thread` class, however at the same time, class that want to enable the `@abstractmethod` must inherit `abc.ABC` class. Because multiple inheritance is a bad practice, can i achieve what i want to do without multiple inheritance ?

For context, i was following the example code from here https://vmois.dev/python-flask-background-thread/. Here are example of abstract class for thread-related class

```
import threading
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
class BackgroundThread(threading.Thread, ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self._stop_event.set()

    def _stopped(self) -> bool:
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    @abstractmethod
    def startup(self) -> None:
        """
        Method that is called before the thread starts.
        Initialize all necessary resources here.
        :return: None
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def shutdown(self) -> None:
        """
        Method that is called shortly after stop() method was called.
        Use it to clean up all resources before thread stops.
        :return: None
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def handle(self) -> None:
        """
        Method that should contain business logic of the thread.
        Will be executed in the loop until stop() method is called.
        Must not block for a long time.
        :return: None
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def run(self) -> None:
        """
        This method will be executed in a separate thread
        when start() method is called.
        :return: None
        """
        self.startup()
        while not self._stopped():
            self.handle()
        self.shutdown()
```

It can be seen that the BackgroundThread inherit `threading.Thread` to enable threading and inherit `abc.ABC` to enable @abstractmethod. Can i refactor the code above so it does not use multiple inheritance ?

Comment: why do you say that multiple inheritance is a bad practice?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because it adds unnecessary complexity and ambiguity (one of good example is the diamond problem) to code, and if not used properly can create anti-pattern in the code. It is discussed on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218458/is-there-any-real-reason-multiple-inheritance-is-hated . Multiple inheritance is so bad that even java does not allow it before java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would composition work? Here's the same code with the abstract portion split out from `BackgroundThread` into an abstract `ThreadHandler` class.

```py
import logging
import queue
import threading
import time
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class ThreadHandler(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def startup(self) -> None:
        """
        Method that is called before the thread starts.
        Initialize all necessary resources here.
        :return: None
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def shutdown(self) -> None:
        """
        Method that is called shortly after stop() method was called.
        Use it to clean up all resources before thread stops.
        :return: None
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def handle(self) -> None:
        """
        Method that should contain business logic of the thread.
        Will be executed in the loop until stop() method is called.
        Must not block for a long time.
        :return: None
        """
        raise NotImplementedError()


class BackgroundThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, handler: ThreadHandler):
        super().__init__()
        self._handler = handler
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self._stop_event.set()

    def _stopped(self) -> bool:
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self) -> None:
        """
        This method will be executed in a separate thread
        when start() method is called.
        :return: None
        """
        self._handler.startup()
        while not self._stopped():
            self._handler.handle()
        self._handler.shutdown()
```

You would then provide a concrete instance of a handler to the constructor of the `BackgroundThread`. Here is an example inspired by the resource you linked to.

```py
TASKS_QUEUE = queue.Queue()


class NotificationHandler(ThreadHandler):
    def startup(self) -> None:
        logging.info("NotificationThread started")

    def shutdown(self) -> None:
        logging.info("NotificationThread stopped")

    def handle(self) -> None:
        try:
            task = TASKS_QUEUE.get(block=False)
            # send_notification(task)
            logging.info(f"Notification for {task} was sent.")
        except queue.Empty:
            time.sleep(1)


notification_thread = BackgroundThread(NotificationHandler())
```

Comment: Oh right, i can just create a thread class that inherit `threading.Thread` and receives handler class in `__init__`, the handler class is the class who inherit the abstract class. Didnt thought about that before, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have to inherit from `abc.ABC` to enable abstract methods. You need your class's metaclass to be `abc.ABCMeta` or a subclass of that. `abc.ABC` is just provided as a way to do that for people less comfortable with metaclasses.

If you don't want to use multiple inheritance, just specify the metaclass directly:

```
import abc

class BackgroundThread(threading.Thread, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    ...
```